# Angular5 / Webworker - Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not

Tags: angular5, web-worker

I try to follow all these tutorials about webworker, but no one works. This is one of them: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135

I follow step by step but after I run `npm start` I get a

> `ERROR in Error: Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
>       at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (D:\PROJECTS_TIQ\w3\worky\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js:121:15)
>       at Promise.resolve.then.then (D:\PROJECTS_TIQ\w3\worky\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:240:54)
>       at <anonymous>
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:608:3`

this is my main.ts .. I think the problem is here, but what..?

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { bootstrapWorkerUi } from '@angular/platform-webworker';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapWorkerUi('webworker.bunde.js')
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

also..  this tutorial talks about some kind of `AotPlugin` that should be in the `webpack.config.js` .. but when I do `npm eject` there is no `AotPlugin` imported in the confg(?)